# Signal switching in oscilloscope

Tags: pcb, switches, relay, signal, oscilloscope

I have an oscilloscope with two probes and a few repetitive tests to run on quite a few boards.

The first probe is always connected to the same test point, but the second probe should be connected to a different test point each test, this means that I do not intend to have real time multiplexing, but rather a simple signal switch on the oscilloscope probe every 20 seconds or so.

I can already run the tests via some simple scripts I made, the problem is the setup of each test where I need to manually change the probe, which for the amount of orders I have is tedious at best.

I was thinking of building a signal switcher using a couple of relays to perform the signal switching, or an off the shelf relay board. Unfortunately I can't afford a DAQ, which I believe would be ideal. I am not looking for extreme accuracy and the signals are 100kHz at most.

Any suggestions for this scenario?
Thank you.

EDIT 1:

The PCBs I need to run the tests on is simply a microcontroller that for different operating voltages supplies different PWM frequencies on different pins.

The first probe of the oscilloscope is connected to the test point of the operating voltage, the second probe is connected to five different pins of the microcontroller, depending on the test that is running, right now I have to set the probe manually between tests.

From the tests, I modify the operating voltage of the power supply, then I start the acquisition on the oscilloscope and when it is finished I save the two waveforms from the different probes of the oscilloscope to my computer, that is a complete test, there is no analysis of the waveform.

I think I can play with a SPDT relay and tristated to achieve this but I have yet to try. I am looking to see if anyone can provide pointers or ideas.

Comment: Please spend more time describing exactly what tests you are performing and why. I get that this is for a lot of boards, so efficiency of time is desired. But I can't say, after reading twice, that I actually understand what you are really doing. And it's not as though we are idiots. We can understand your tests, I imagine. We just need to see what you are on about. I think then you can get a really good answer that will help.

Comment: I will add more details.

Comment: Added more details.

Comment: There are USB controlled multi-relay boards but beware of wet and dry signals. Once a relay switches a wet signal don't use it for dry.

Comment: Since your signals are 'simple', would it be easier to obtain 4 additional probes; connect one to each test point, and swap between signals by plugging the appropriate one into the scope ?

Comment: @jp314 If manual switching is tolerable a rotary switch could be used.

Comment: For a production test jig it is not unreasonable to use relays.  You can get relays for RF, high current/voltage etc.  Many of the test and measurement companies make them. If you have less exacting requirements you could use an Arduino and some relay boards or something similar. Maybe something like a cd4051 analog switch chip might do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Now you know that you failed to design for Test or DFT.

This usually consists of an interface of all the functional nodes. Then you design a multiplexer with a simple D/A to inject signals for a 30 automated second test.

Even better DFT is BIST.  Look it up and do that on your next design.

Back in 1980 we had one motherboard with lots of IO for telephony, modems, serial ports and display. The designer downloaded self testcode  to board and the self testing took 30 seconds with fault codes to isolate any failure.

It took him 1 day to design the code and it worked 1st time. This was a subscriber board for a home trial called Project IDA with 1.544 MBps DS1 full duplex to each home.

Apologies for being critical at first, but you will learn to design better next time.

Comment: Problem is this is required by the customer, that is why there is no analysis of the waveforms from my side, they do that part, I just need to provide the data.

Comment: I do my own tests using cmocka by the way, off and on the board, but I get what you are saying.